# Convert python list of string to bytearray

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion, concatenation, pyserial

I would write a list on serial COM through pySerial.

I create a list of string, where each string is a parameter, and then I pass the list to serial write function. There is an error because I cannot write list of string directly on serial

This is my code:

```
import datetime
import time
import sys
import serial

date = datetime.datetime.now()
dateStr = str(date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
unixTime = int(time.time())
crc = str("1234")


packet = list()

packet.append('test')
packet.append(dateStr)
packet.append(unixTime)
packet.append('4')
packet.append('81')
packet.append('1')
packet.append('0')

packet.append('00.7')
packet.append('4')
packet.append('9')
packet.append('0')

packet.append('18.8')
packet.append('5')
packet.append('3')
packet.append('0')

packet.append('15.3')
packet.append('4')
packet.append('6')
packet.append('0')

packet.append('2')
packet.append('0')
packet.append('13')
packet.append('0')

packet.append('0')
packet.append('0')
packet.append('185.6')

# add semicolon between list elements
serialCOM.write(packet)
```

Is there a way to concatenate each list elements into a list or bytearray?

Furthermore I need to add a semicolon between each list elements.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: did you try the `';'.join(packet)`?

Comment: Also, the list has the `.extend()` method. Instead of writing multiple lines of appends, just use `packet.extend(['4', '81', '1', '0'])`.

Comment: My problem regards the list elements which contains string. For example packet[0], packet[1], packet[2]. I looking for a method to convert the list into a linear string which contains the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an actual bytearray object, pass the list into the bytearray constructor.

```
serialCOM.write(bytearray(packet))
```

Note that `unixTime` is not converted to a string so you must convert that first.

But what you probably want (based on the comment about semicolons) is to just join the strings using the join method of a string like this:

```
# Force all items in the list to be strings
msg = ';'.join(map(str,packet))
serialCOM.write(msg)
```

The result of the join is then:

```
In[50]: ';'.join(map(str,packet))
Out[50]: 'test;17-10-2016;1476708605;4;81;1;0;00.7;4;9;0;18.8;5;3;0;15.3;4;6;0;2;0;13;0;0;0;185.6'
```

Comment: Thanks **frmdstryr**! That is exactly what I looking for! Another question: the string **msg** must starts with "0x02" and end with "0x03". This are the STX and ETX byte. To write non printable characters on serialCom, Will I use bytearray? Can I add 0x02 to byte array, convert and concatenate the **msg** and finally add 0x03?

Comment: Yes, You can create bytes using '\x<hex>' like. '\x02' and '\x03'.